# A/C - Repeated Freon Leaks & Run Capacitators/Fan failures

Tags: air-conditioning, central-air

My senior citizen father has a home warranty policy.  Different contractors have worked on the A/C every year since 2011.  He services it in the spring and changes the filter regularly, but we live in Phoenix, Arizona.

He has never been able to turn his A/C down below 78 degrees or the unit freezes up.  We've communicated this to each contractor.

When the A/C stops working every summer since 2011, he has had repeated freon leaks in his A/C unit.  It appears from service records from the warranty company's contractors that they continue to use StopLeak, charge him for 2-4 lbs of Freon, and then the same thing happens again later that summer or again the next Arizona summer when temps are above 110 degrees.  They've never replaced the coils or the air handler.

The run capacitators were also replaced in 2014, 2015, 2017.  The fan motor was also replaced twice in 2017.

Finally, a contractor recommended that the air handler be replaced and the warranty company only wants to replace the coils and to charge my father for all the retrofitting to "bring it up to standards" which I dont understand.

My questions are:
 1.  Would repeated Freon leaks that aren't fixed cause the damage to the Run Capacitators & Fan motors?

2. If the STOP LEAK doesn't fix the leak permanently, isnt this a red flag that the coil or entire air handler need to be replaced?
3. Because the A/C thermostat couldnt be turned down below 78 without freezing up the unit, is this obvious that the Freon has been leaking since 2011 and they've never made the proper repair?
4. Given the 2020 regulations depleting the supply of parts for A/C using R-22, what would you recommend he do?  Get the air handler fixed at an out of pocket cost of 2,000?  Fix the coil at an out-of-pocket cost of $1,000?  He is on a fixed income and cannot afford to replace his A/C unit to one using R-410a.
5. Referring to the air handler or the coils, What is required to "bring it up to standards?"
6. If the repairs had been made properly any time in the last 8 summers when it broke, would the cost to "bring it up to standards" have been less?

Thanks for helping me protect my 81 year old senior citizen father!

Comment: Way to broad of an ac question. In my professional opinion stop leak is a joke, my apprentice bought a vending machines after several classes and some training, short story he was screwed. He tried some of the stop leak scams and after they failed asked me for help, no good idea he same thing can be true with ac units, been there done that. If your ac needs more than a filter change every year get a new company.

Comment: Keep in mind the insurance company's job is to deny claims. They will say any possible garbage to talk you out of pursuing a claim, and that works partly because nobody reads the contract so they don't know what it actually covers.  So you have to be a dog with a bone, and they do have the option of not talking to you, since you're not technically a party.

Comment: My father has given me power of attorney to talk to them and I handled claims for an insurance carrier for 20 years so I'm appalled by how they are handling the claim.  I have that expertise but not the expertise on the A/C system.  Hoping some people can provide me insight on whether the repairs over the last 8 years were appropriate if it had been a typical A/C contractor